# Group by parts of a field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a novice to Elasticsearch so please go easy on me.

I have a list of product sub-types which are part of the full product id which also contains product height and width.

Example: Product Sub-type 15, Height 5, Width 5 > Product id: S15H5W5

Now, this product sub-type is part of multiple product types which is also included in the index.

So the data looks like following:

```
{ PID: "S15H5W5", PT: "A-1" }
{ PID: "S15H7W7", PT: "A-1" }
{ PID: "S20H10W10", PT: "A-1" }
{ PID: "S15H7W5", PT: "B-2" }
{ PID: "S50H8W19", PT: "C-3"}
```

Expected output:

```
{ SUBTYPE: "15", PC: [ { PT: "A-1", COUNT: "2" }, { PT: "B-2", COUNT: "1" } ]  
{ SUBTYPE: "20", PC: [ { PT: "A-1", COUNT: "1" } ]  
{ SUBTYPE: "50", PC: [ { PT: "C-3", COUNT: "1" } ]
```

I am able to match parts of product id (*15* *20* *50*) using query_string, but I cannot use product sub-type as a grouping field because it is not part of the original database.

Is there something I can do? Thanks!

Comment: PID is of type “text”.

Comment: Are you looking for the exact output or somewhat similar?

Comment: I am looking for the exact output, I will use it for plotting a chart.